# Using nmcli, can I point to a .nmconnection file and connect to that without importing it?

Tags: nmcli

Say I have a file called `$HOME/my-vpn.nmconnection`

```
[connection]
id=whatever
uuid=whatever
type=vpn
autoconnect=false
...etc

[vpn]
gateway=whatever
...etc
```

Is it possible to use the `nmcli` to arbitrary use that as a connection?
Something like:

```
nmcli conn up path $HOME/my-vpn.nmconnection
```

Answer (score 4):

That profile file should be called `keyfile`, it should be in

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

This file must be owned by root and be readably only by root - otherwise NetworkManager will ignore it:

```
sudo chmod -R 600 /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyConnection.nmconnection
sudo chown -R root:root /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MyConnection.nmconnection
```

When you have your own file there with correct permissions, just a reload:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

can know that file, then you can do this:

```
sudo nmcli con up MyConnection
```

There is no `path` keyword in the command.

Files outside that path (or readable by non-root users) are unknown to NetworkManager.

Please also refer to:

```
man nm-settings-keyfile
```

Comment: It would be nice if NetworkManager at least logged that it was ignoring a connection due to permissions!

Comment: I'm unsure if it logs that, but in my case I did see, in systemd journal (`journalctl -e`), it logging why it pretends a connection doesn't exist. It was a mistype in my case lol